# a layout with ellipsis then a counter

Tags: android

I'm new to Android, please help me to design below layout. Many thanks.

I want to implement a layout, it shows a text followed by a counter. If the text is too long, show ... followed by counter. like below:

Expected layout:

Short text (3)              // when screen width is enough

Long text blah bl...(2)     // when screen width isn't enough

Below are my xml. It shows normally for above 1, when text is short. When text is long, the problem are:
1) it doesn't show "..." at the end of text
2) counter (2) isn't shown on screen.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" 
    >

    <TextView android:id="@+id/text" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="very long body safbadaf asfasf safasfd"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:paddingLeft="4dp" android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:paddingRight="4dp" android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" android:singleLine="true" android:ellipsize="end"/>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/count" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="count"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:paddingLeft="4dp" android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:paddingRight="4dp" android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" android:singleLine="true" android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

William

Answer (score 1):

set `android:layout_weight="1"` for the first textview and not the second one. Also set layout_width="0" for the first textview instead of wrap_content

Comment: Frieza, Thank you! but "0" isn't valid value of layout_width.